# Which is the most commonly used way to implement user signup and login?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm starting out with Django development and I feel very confused and lost about all the ways you can implement the same thing. It all is very jumbled in my head right now (Class-based forms? Class-based views? Function-based views with Class-based forms? Custom HTML forms which are bound to Forms class and then *etc etc etc...*)

---

So far these are all the intertwined options that I see and they confuse me a lot:

- **Plain HTML forms** which are then bound to the `Form` instance in views for validation *(?)*. Every view is custom. (I like this one the best because I don't find any joy in using `{{ form }}` in templates, plus this one seem to be straightforward for me) Is `forms.py` not used when you implement forms that way?
- `include('django.contrib.auth.urls')` for login with custom templates (in which you when use `{{ form }}` and then something else for signup because there is no same built-in thing for signing up
- `UserCreationForm` but you have to extend it somehow if you want to add more fields (why are there built-in views for authentication but not for user creation btw?)
- Custom class-based forms if you want to use them with custom user models

***What should I use if there would be extra data associated with User on registration? What is the most commonly way Django developers use in general?***

---

Sorry if I'm not making much sense, I'm overwhelmed of the multiple ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I know is using built-in Django contrib module like `UserCreationForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms` for `signup` function and `AuthenticationForm` for `login`. Below are my codes in `views.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
    AuthenticationForm, 
    UserCreationForm,
)
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login,
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])    
def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('articles:index')
        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('articles:index')       
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request,'accounts/signup.html', context)

@require_http_methods(['GET','POST'])
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('articles:index')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())
            return redirect(request.GET.get('next') or 'articles:index')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```